# How to use the CSS of the Wordpress core in the development of my administration page?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, admin

I am currently creating the administration window for my wordpress plugin, my objective is to create this screen using the same CSS that are already used within the different tabs of the "wordpress administrator". **My question is if there is any link (or list of links) where all the CSS classes used by the Wordpress core are defined to render the "Wordpress administrator"** (something like Bootstrap has in its documentation [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/tables/))

At the moment I was able to perform some experiments using the information in this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes) as well as analyzing with my browser the classes that have applied some parts of the HTML code

[image]

If there is not what I consult in my first question, t**he only thing I would have left to use these CSS styles would be to analyze the part that interests me with the browser and see the classes they have applied to then put them in my code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frank Bültge has a plugin which displays all (most?) of the WP admin styles, which is kept fairly up-to-date:
https://github.com/bueltge/WordPress-Admin-Style

Helen Hou-Sandí also has a plugin style guide:
https://github.com/helen/wp-style-guide

There is also this:
https://dotorgstyleguide.wordpress.com/